# Periodically checking if the bluetooth device is in range or not - .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a mobile application with VS2008 which has a capacbility of periodically checking if the desired bluetooth device is in range or not. At the moment, I am using System.windows.form.Timer to do this. However, I have found that it will slow down the application, even worse, it will crash sometimes.

Does anyone have any better idea of how to do periodically checking without using the System.windows.form.timer? I am currently using 32 feets for the bluetooth.

Thanks for any helps in advance.

Regards,

Charles

Comment: You're working with System.Windows.Forms in C and not C++ or C#?

Comment: Im working with C# in winform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a background thread that sleeps for X amount of time (you choose how long) then every once in a while (based on how long the thread sleeps) it will run (wake up and execute), check if the bluetooth is in range and give you some form of feed back, then it will go to sleep again.

Summed up

1. Thread activates
2. Checks if bluetooth is in range
3. Gives you feed back
4. Thread goes to sleep again

   ```
   while (true)
   {
      //starts a new thread
      Thread blueToothThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(menu.Run));
   }

   //the threads method named Run
   public void Run()
   {
       // Perform the bluetooth check here

       Console.WriteLine("You will see this only once every 8 seconds");
       //choose how long thread sleeps here
       Thread.Sleep(8000);
   }
   ```

Comment: However, How can I use WHILE loop to do this? Because the checking is not time-limited. It can run as long as it can. Does this approach slow down the application especially UI?

Comment: It will run as long as it can, what limits the time is how long the thread sleeps for, becoure you continue look into what [threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.80).aspx) is and if the thread is in a `while(true)` infinite loop with `Thread.Sleep(8000);` it means the thread will execute only ONCE every 8 seconds.

Comment: Ok. I see what you meant. You are saying that I should use a flag which set it to true or false. If true, run the check, otherwise, it stops check. However, Do I need to use Thread to avoid freeze

Comment: Not what im saying at all, you always call the thread constantly, the thread will know when to sleep or not based on its delegate void method because thats where you tell it to sleep, if when called the thread is sleeping, it will do nothing, so there is less overhead than using a timer. As for the crashes we need to see some errors and some code to determine why this is happening.

Comment: what is difference between using the timer and the above approach? Does it mean the above approach will run periodic task in seperate thread while the timer is running in the main thread.

Comment: The Thread.Sleep() mechanism removes the need for a timer, the timer is not necessary when the thread has a sleeping mechanism.

So the thread above runs independently of any other threads other than its parent thread (its main thread) which is good, because if you stop the main thread it means you've stopped the whole application.

Now for your program, you will want to check if the bluetooth is in range and call this thread somewhere, where it will be getting called all the time (for example in an infinite loop), the thread will get called when its sleeping but thats ok, it wont do anything.

Comment: Thanks Lyuben. I will have a try with this approach tomorrow. In your above code, do I need to add bluetoothThread.Start() inside the WHILE loop?

Comment: One more question. In UI, I have a button which calls the "StartDeviceCheck" function which will include your above code. Will it be better to declare the Thread in the class level such Private Thread bluetoothThread. So that if user click "Stop" button, it just invokes Thread.Abort() which terminates the thread.

Comment: If you do that the thread will run only once the class object has been declared, but if its your top level class that is ok, whether its private or public depends on what you are doing with it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. if I call the above code in a function, will it be only invoked once? Should I put the While loop inside the RUN method, so when it is true, it will run the check. In general, when I start the bluetoothThread, it will start checking. does it work?

Comment: yes do that, place the call to the thread somewhere where it will run in a constant loop

Comment: Hi , one more question. If I place a thread in a function level, not private Thread thread;, will the thread in the functionn teminate automatically once the code execution is finished? Or do i need to terminate manually?

Comment: depends on the loop that its in, what happens is the thread runs in a loop, and the method (in the above called Run() will execute from start to end) but you must terminate the thread on its own.